# Method of rewriting ODE into its Exact Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Im going over class notes and can't figure out how my professor rewrote an equation, he skip going over the method because class was near ending and there was something more important later on in the the problem he wanted us to know.

The equation is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x+y^3} \tag{1}$$ 
and the rewritten form is $$\frac{1}{y}-\frac{x+y^3}{y^2}y^{'}=0\tag{2}$$
I can understand how the $\frac{1}{y}$ comes into play

$$\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x+y^3}\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{y}dy=\frac{dx}{x+y^3}$$
but as for dividing the right side by $y^2$ I cannot see a path there.

Comment: Is your question about writing (1) in form (2) and vice versa?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yeah, I know the the structure of the exact equation, I just need to help on getting to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a linear equation hidden in this seemingly non-linear equation. You get it if you consider the inverse function $x(y)$ (assuming you consider some solution where $y(x)$ is not constant). Then $y'=1/x'$, so that
$$
yx'(x)-x-y^3=0.
$$
Now you apply the standard methods for finding integrating factors or directly recognize the numerator of the derivative
$$
\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{x(y)}{y}\right)=\frac{yx'(y)-x(y)}{y^2}=y.
$$
If you want you can write this also as an exact equation
$$
\frac{y\,dx-x\,dy}{y^2}-y\,dy=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a matter of algebraic manipulations.

From (2) to (1) is just about solving for $y'$ and using the Leibnis notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $y'$.

From (1) to (2) multiply equation (1) by $\frac{x+y^3}{y}$ to get
$$\frac{x+y^3}{y}y'=1$$
which is equivalent to
$$1-\frac{x+y^3}{y}y'=0\tag{3}$$

Then multiply (3) by $\frac{1}{y}$

Of course, since we are nor setting initial conditions, we should not worry about dividing by zero at this point.

Comment: I know you're just answering my question but how would I know that I need to multiply by $\frac{1}{y}$?

Comment: You don't need to principle. The reason why sometimes it is convenient to multiply ODEs by some functional factor is to use some separation method to solve them.  For instance equations of the form $\partial_xF dx + \partial_yF dy=0$ are easy to solve. So you may want to see if ny multiplying $M(x,y)dx + N(x,y) dy=0$ by some factor, you may get something life the order equation.

Comment: The additional factor $1/y$ in my solution make the ODE to be of the form $\partial_x F dx +\partial_y F dy=0$, where $F(x,y)=\frac{x}{y} +\frac12 y^2$.

Comment: In your class you will see a few methods that allow you to convert a general equation of the form $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ into $\partial_xFdx+\partial_yFdy=0$.