# Solving a Initial Value ODE using exact equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The given equation and its resulting equations
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x+y^3}$$

$$M(x,y)=ydx$$
$$N(x,y)=(x+y^3)dy$$
Checking if the equation is exact by partial differentiation

$$M_{y}=1$$
$$N_{x}=1$$
So now to integrate them respectively
$$\int x+y^3dy=xy+\frac{1}{4}y^4+g_1(x)$$ 
$$\int ydx=xy+g_2(y)$$
Now I see they have like terms and the first one's 2nd term is only dependent on $y$ so that can be used in place of $g_2$. But after that I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: The De is not exact...

Comment: See also the earlier question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3543167/115115 about how to make this equation exact.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x+y^3}$$
$${(x+y^3)}{dy}-{y}{dx}=0$$
$${y}{dx}-{(x+y^3)}{dy}=0$$
$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$
This is not an exact differential equation.
$$\partial_y M \ne \partial_x N$$
$$1 \ne -1$$

---

Here is a solution:
$${y}{dx}-{(x+y^3)}{dy}=0$$
$${y}{dx}-xdy-y^3{dy}=0$$
$$\frac {{y}{dx}-xdy}{y^2}-y{dy}=0$$
$$d \left ( \frac x y \right )-\frac 12{dy^2}=0$$
Integrate.
$$ \left ( \frac x y \right )-\frac 12{y^2}=C$$
$x$ is a function of $y$
$$  x(y) =\frac 12{y^3}+Cy$$

Note that the original equation is linear if you consider $x'$ instead of $y'$

$$x'{y}={x+y^3}$$
And it's easy to solve ( with integrating factor for example). Or rewrite it as:
$$\dfrac {x'{y}-{x}}{y^2}=y$$
$$\implies \left (\frac x y \right )'=y$$

Comment: How do you know that the two functions with be subtracted and not added?

Comment: Multiply both sides by denominator  @EricBrown

Comment: What did you do right before you integrated?

Comment: @EricBrown I added a line Eric I hope it's more clear

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way to solve the differential equation which is mentioned at the end of Isham's answer. Starting from

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x+y^3}$$

Rewrite the equation as

$$x+y^3=y\frac{dx}{dy}$$ 
which implies
$$\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{1}{y}x = y^2$$
This equation is a linear first order differential equation of the form
$$\frac{dx}{dy}+P(y)x =Q(y)$$
where
$$P(y)=-\frac{1}{y}$$
and the integrating factor is
$$\mu(y)=\text{exp}\Big(\int P(y)dy\Big)=\frac{1}{y}$$
so the equation becomes
$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=y$$
which after integrating forms
$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{y^2}{2}+C$$
or
$$x(y)=\frac{y^3}{2}+Cy$$